# Which tables do not have indexes in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, indexing, sqlplus

On Oracle, how can I list ALL tables and ALL materialized views without indexes using a SELECT command ?

Comment: What have you tried?  You'll need to use the `dba_|all_|user_tables` and `dba_|all_|user_indexes` tables.  I'd use a `NOT EXISTS` but there are many ways to write the query.  Depending on your privileges and the scope of what you want to look at (are you looking just at the current schema, all tables that you have access to, all tables in the system, etc.).  It probably doesn't make sense, for example, to look at tables owned by SYS or SYSTEM.

Comment: thanks man, i think it  works with this query..
" select ut.table_name,ui.table_type from user_tables ut,user_indexes ui where ut.table_name!=ui.table_name; "

Comment: That seems unlikely to give you a useful result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, normally I wouldn't do this, but here you go:

```
SELECT t.TABLE_NAME
  FROM USER_TABLES t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
                     FROM USER_INDEXES) i
    ON i.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
  WHERE i.TABLE_NAME IS NULL;
```

Perhaps your question should be "Why did someone just do my homework for me?".

Best of luck.

Comment: Best of luck on your final.

Comment: Bob, I literally need this for a production situation where we're recreating thousands of tables and then doing operations on them - need to ensure there are indexes to reduce time from 3 hours to 9 minutes...why do you think this is a homework task?